# Broken styles issue with React-snap

Tags: prerender, react-native-web, react-snap

We have created a web app using react native web. We want to add a server-side rendering to our app. We have added a code to render the page server-side, but it's not working, I can see the blank white page in the network preview tab and the server only sends my index.html file as a response.

I found some articles that are suggesting to use prerendering of the app.
To add prerendering to our app I tried react-snap (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snap), a snapshot is created but when I started the app it's only loading the first page(landing page) of the app, No events are working on this page(click events) and styles are also missing, there is no way to navigate in the app.

Expectations: The app should be server-side rendered, I should see the snapshot of the page in the network preview, the server should return a snapshot of the page in the response.

Can anyone suggest a solution to fix this?